# Errors when running the soccer simulation 2d

Tags: 2d, simulation

I use fedora and just installed the soccer simulation server 2d(rcssserver-15.0.0) and another piece of software beside it. Then I downloaded a base code. When I  want to run it 
 I type `./start.sh` in the base code directory. For first time there was no problem, but when I wanted to run it the second time by the same base code I got this error:

```
[reza@localhost WrightEagleBASE-3.0.0]$ ./start.sh
cd Release; make -j3 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reza/Soccer/WrightEagleBASE-3.0.0/Release'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reza/Soccer/WrightEagleBASE-3.0.0/Release'
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Goalie: 1
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 2
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 3
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 4
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 5
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 6
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 7
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 8
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 9
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 10
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Player: 11
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagleBASE Coach
WrightEagleBASE: Connect Server Error ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change team name second time. By default it's `WrightEagleBASE`. When you run it second time the same name is used. You could pass this argument to binary file:
`./WrightEagleBASE -team_name SOMENAME` to add members to the second team.

Comment: you can change the name the team in start.sh file